# Jquery contains to remove certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p>some string here xxx</p>
```

I want to remove the xxx characters

so I do `$(p:contains('xxx')).remove();` but it removed the entire `<p></p>`, how to only get rid of the targeted character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the `text` method and a string `replace`

```
$('p').text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.replace('xxx', '');
});
```

`remove` removes entire elements, not parts of text.

Comment: what is the first param? _?

Answer (score 5):

That is the expected behavior of `remove()`, it removes whole elements . You can use `text(fn)` or `html(fn)` to do it.

```
$("p:contains('xxx')").text(function(idx, oldText){    
  return oldText.replace('xxx','');
});
```

If you also have other tags within the `p` use `html(fn)` as above